# i am facing error while running uipath bot related to Excel

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am facing the issue while running EXCEL related bot in the UIPATH tool. The error which I am facing is given here[20.4.1

> Message: Job stopped with an unexpected exit code: 0xC0000005
>
> Exception Type: System.Exception
>
> RemoteException wrapping System.Exception: Job stopped with an unexpected exit code: 0xC0000005]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure how someone should help you. I missed to tell what you did to force the error. Also you miss to tell what you have tried so far. So did you try to kill the excel process already and try again? Not a good question. Please read how to use SO please.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of questions in your question...but I've had issues similar to yours before and they were caused by the following:

1. Kill Excel - doing a kill Excel process while Excel was doing something at the time or in the background. I usually add Delays of 5-10 seconds before doing any kill Excel.
2. Accessing/performing an Excel activity or action without the necessary data present. So the example that comes to mind is if you try to update a Pivot Table, but the pivot table is linked to another file (call it Source.xlsx)...so if this Source.xlsx was not downloaded, then Excel would prompt an error while performing the update Pivot table activity. So pretty much, if you try to perform an Excel activity without the necessary files or data that you would use on a real scenario, then it will give you an error.
3. Settings...so from your antivirus to Excel itself, there can be settings "blocking" something that is used to perform the process you want and that could be why you are getting the error.

These are all general answers to a very broad question...my advice is to check again the logic of your bot...debug and check that all files are downloaded/data is present accordingly before doing the Excel activity (you can use break points). You can also try googling about the error# you-re getting :)

Finally, If you decide to use macros of Excel in your bot, make sure that these macros have error handling, otherwise your bot might give unexpected errors or get trapped in a loop...https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/ can be used as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Package and select the excel package and install 2.7.2 package and save it.

I faced the same problem and installed v2.7.2 package and it worked for me.

Refer below link for more info.
https://forum.uipath.com/t/remoteexception-wrapping-system-exception-job-stopped-with-an-unexpected-exit-code-0xc0000005/173595/16

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvWnc.png)